# How to check if node is an attribute

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a node that I receive as a result of selection by XPath. 
Can I check if this node is an attribute?

Code example:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new StringInputStream(xml));
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(path);
DTMNodeList result = (DTMNodeList) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
Node node = result.item(0);//how to check if this node is an attribute
```

Example XML:

```
<a atr='asdf'></a>
```

XPATH:

```
/a/@atr
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {
   ...
```